# Internal computer screen cracked

Tags: windows-8, display, lcd, physical-damage

I did something stupid. I work on my computer on the ground, and so I tripped on my computer and closed it. It is a Windows 8 (now Windows 8.1) HP PC. The next day I open it up and I find it cracked. The outer screen is not cracked, but it appears that the inner screen is cracked. Having some knowledge in how computers are made, it looks like the screen has multiple layers and one of them is cracked. I just hit <kbd>prt sc</kbd> and pasted it into Paint.

The cracked layer hasn’t messed up the screen copying at all. About half of the screen is cracked and I can’t see what is there. There is what looks like a green powder or something that comes out of the cracks. I can’t tell if it is messed up pixels or some sort of powder in the monitor because the crack is internal. There are green and magenta (I think it is magenta) vertical and horizontal lines going everywhere. The half of the screen that is cracked is mostly white.

My friend told me that my LCD panel in the PC is what got cracked. So what can I do?

Comment: **The cracked layer hasn’t messed up the screen copying at all**  **:D**
`Print Screen` doesn't work that way

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is right, the LCD cracked. There isn't much you can do other than replacing it or getting someone else to replace it. If you happened to have a spare monitor you could use that for now as this should still work.